# Wordpress content text HTML tags not saving after click update on visualr edior

Tags: html, wordpress

I try to understand why WordPress source code is not saving with `<p>` or `<br />` tags in database.

*This is an image from the content editor source code.*

[image]

*This is an image from the database content field.*

[image]

How to make that the tags stayed on do not disappear when saving?

Answer (score 0):

Now it working). I used TinyMCE plugin for editor and in settings of plugin have checkbox and all working as I want

[image]